# Getting Self existing commits from master branch doesn't create merge conflict Gerrit

Tags: git, merge, gerrit, rebase

I am learner to Gerrit. We have started using Gerrit code review. But we are facing some problems.

We are following below process in Gerrit for code review.

We have two branches. One is `master` and other is `refs/for/master`.We have checked out master branch to work upon.

We have to push our changes in Gerrit in  `refs/for/master`. After code reviewed those changed are merged into `master` branch. But before pushing our changes to `refs/for/master`. We have to take pull of `master` branch.

If I have commited some commit to `refs/for/master` branch. After getting code reviewed, I am taking pull of `master` branch and rebasing it. Would It not show merge conflict of pulling same files that I myself committed to `refs/for/master` branch?

My Second Query is related to merge conflict.If some other developer has done some changes into file and pushed to `refs/for/master` branch for getting code reviewd. I myself have done same changes and pushed to `refs/for/master` for code review.

After getting code reviewed one of us, Other would see merge conflict. 
So How do you manage these things?

Help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you already read the [Gerrit documentation](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/)?

I suggest special attention to the [Basic Gerrit Walkthrough](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/intro-gerrit-walkthrough.html) and the [User Guide](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/intro-user.html) itens where you'll see details about [developing multiple features in parallel](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/intro-user.html#multiple-features), [submit a change](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/intro-user.html#submit) and [rebase a change](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/intro-user.html#rebase).